# How to save the state of HTML page (after jQuery Modification)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, socket.io

Hello I'm creating a `HTML5`/`CSS3`/`javascript` card game which interacts with a `node.js` server and I used `socket.io` as the transport layer between the server and the client.
I want to save the state of the `HTML` page after `jQuery` modifications (a card is dealt or drawn, players connected...) in the server, so when the player disconnect and reconnect the server give him the saved state and he can see the state of the page as he left, or if the player disconnects another player can take his place.

So any mechanism on how to save game state with `jQuery` modifications will be so much appreciated. I've searched a lot but I don't seem to find a solution.

Comment: Well, what about you start by posting what you have searched?

Comment: if all you care about is the html, just use `innerHTML`, but I don't think that's true. You probably need the state of some JS? Your question should have code examples, as of now it's too open ended asking for suggestions but Stack Overflow is for questions about specific pieces of code.

Comment: You probably want to save an object representation of the state and rebuild the HTML accordingly

Comment: i tried innerHTML but it only saves the html that did not help so much

Comment: @verybadalloc i tried saving the inner html but that didn't did it , i tried saving all the emmited signals in sockets , and when a player reconnect he recover all the emmited signals but that didn't work neither

Answer (score 2):

you will probably want to store your state in some sort of js object maybe something like this

```
var state = {
   hand: [
      "4H",
      "7D",
      "3S"
   ],
   money: 1000
}
```

where the 1H would be the 4 of Hearts then you can easily store this on your back end as well as in a cookie or WebSQL or something. Hope this helps!

Comment: but my application is based on DOM elements and their animations (jQuery) , i want to save all the current state of the page the hand , the cards dealt , their positions , the connected players everything

Comment: You don't have to save the DOM but the objects that you used to manipulate it. All those you said above can be data that you save/retrieve from database and then create the page and repopulate